# Significant difference between ionInput and ionChange

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**Q. What's the difference between `(ionInput)` and `(ionChange)`? In which circumstances, should I pick either one of them?**

I've tried both code as shown below, and it gives the same result as I expected.

---

**Example code using ionInput event**

```
<ion-searchbar type="text" maxlength="18" placeholder="Search" debounce="0" 
 [(ngModel)]="usernameText" (ionInput)="findUserWithUsername()"></ion-searchbar>
```

**Example code using ionChange event**

```
<ion-input type="text" maxlength="18" placeholder="Search" clearInput
 [(ngModel)]="usernameText" (ionChange)="findUserWithUsername()"></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is: **It's depend on what component you are using**.
**First**, you need to know, what is `ionInput` and `ionChange`. It is [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) and it is definded inside each component. So it will be different between two components. `ion-tabs` has `ionChange` which will emit whenever the selected tab changed. `ion-input` has `ionChange` which will emit whenever the value of input changed. So these are completely different.
**Second**, not all components have `ionInput`. The same with  `ionChange`.`ion-input` just only has `ionInput`. But `ion-searchbar` has both. 
 
**Finally**, just find out the difference beetwen `ionInput` and `ionChange` of `ion-searchbar`. Lets create a small test:
In `home.html`:

```
<ion-searchbar placeholder="Search" debounce="0" (ngModel)]="searchText" (ionChange)="ionChange()" (ionInput)="ionInput()"></ion-searchbar>
```

In `home.ts`:

```
searchText = "111";
ionViewDidLoad(){
   //Change the searck value after 2s the page loaded  
   setTimeout(()=>{ 
      console.log("change from the code");
      this.searchText = "222";
   },2000)
}
```

When user typing in the text box, both event fired. But when the value of `searchText` is changed by code, only `ionChange` fired. So we can conclude that **in  `ion-searchbar` component `ionInput` event fired whenever user typing in the textbox and `ionChange` fired whenever the value of textbox changed.**
Here is the [live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ioninput-vs-ionchange)

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer Duannx. Helped me a lot to understand the difference between two event emitters.

Comment: Glad i could help :-)

Answer (score 4):

I have tried `(ionInput)` but did not fired any event in it .
then I tried `(input)` then it worked for me.
So make sure you are correct at it or may be i am missing at some point.

Now difference between `(input)` & `(ionChange)`

- `(input)` :    This event fires when user tries to enter value in input field, it will fire even when user copy same value and paste it in field. because it does not mater which value is get entered in it.
- `(ionChange)`:  This event fires only when user change value of input field. if user copy and paste same value it will not get fired.but if user enters different value then it will fire. because it matters values of input field.

Hope this information will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Devang. That's weird (ionInput) works completely fine for me.

Comment: ionChange event still gets fired when I paste the same value in the field.

Answer (score 3):

Another significant difference is when you use the `debounce` property. `debounce` only affects `ionChange` but not `ionInput`. This can be handy in specific situations when you would like to perform certain operations before the `ionChange` event is triggered.

The effect of the `debounce` property is best felt when using  `[(ngModel)]` on `ion-searchbar`, which has a default `debounce` of 250ms. When you use `ionInput`, the value will always omit the characters typed in the last 250ms, meaning `ionChange` would be ideal unless the `debounce` property is set to 0.